Bash: Comparing User Input To A String Isn't Working
Here's the entire script:
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter name please:"
read name
echo "your name is $name."
read randominput
echo "Are you ok?"
read feeling
if ["$feeling" = "yes"]
then
echo "Nice!"
fi

When I run the script, everything works fine, until after the read feeling line. I then get this error:
./practice.sh: Zeile 9: [yes: Befehl nicht gefunden
Which is german and means in eglisch something like:
./practice.sh: line 9: [yes: command not found
If give it a different input, I get the same error, except [yes: is now [somethingelse:
How do I fix this error?
I was trying to write a script, where the user would have to answer a question, and an if statement would then decide the output depending on the answer.
Thank you for the help in advance!

you need a space after [ and before ]; fwiw, cut-n-paste your entire script (including shebang) into shellcheck.net to get help with addressing these types of syntax issues

markp-fuso already explained the basic problem in your code, but in case you wondered, why in your case [ is not treated as special charcter: Usually, [...] is treated as a wild card expression (glob pattern), but bash does word splitting before filename generation, and hence it "sees" only the [yes part in the first word (i.e. the command), and this command indeed does not exist. You can experiment a bit, by doing on the command line a shopt -s failglob; [yes=yes], which will produce the more helpful error message bash: no match:  [yes=yes].
